# How to eliminate excessive vertical space in wrapfigure?

Tags: spacing, captions, wrapfigure, polyglossia

Compiling the following document using `xelatex` results in unwanted vertical space above the wrapfigure caption. Removing either the inclusion of the `polyglossia` package or `\centercaption` usage eliminates the problem. However, this is not a viable solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\centercaption{%
  \captionsetup{format=plain,labelsep=newline,justification=centering}}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2cm}
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \centercaption
  \caption{test}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Above document produces

[image: Image 1]

Without `polyglossia` the spacing is correct:

[image: Image 2]

Is there any other way to eliminate the excessive vertical space **above** the caption? Note that setting the number of lines to be consumed by `wrapfigure` doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why `polyglossia` adds extra space between the graphic and caption, maybe a bug. You can just use `\centercaption` at the beginning of the `wrapfigure` environment to prevent the extra space it produces.

BTW, `wrapfig` package's `wrapfigure` environment has several optional parameters. The first one is the number of lines it vertically occupies. For your example:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{2cm}
  \centercaption
  \rule{2cm}{2cm}
  \caption{test}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

See the manual of `wrapfig` for more options and decriptions.

Comment: Using `\centercaption` at the beginning of the `wrapfigure` works indeed. Though the solution is not ideal, since it requires to update all `\centercaption` usages in a document which was previously compiled using `pdflatex`.

Comment: Nothing else has worked, but using the [line num] argument has for me anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The extra vertical space that you see is because of the redefinition of `\@esphack` macro in package `fixltx2e` (so obviously user Leo Liu is wrong in saying that this is a polyglossia bug, polyglossia loads fontspec and fontspec loads fixltx2e). The original definition of `\@esphack` in latex.ltx is:

```
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi}
```

And the redefinition of  `\@esphack` in `fixltx2e` is:

```
\def\@esphack{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \spacefactor\@savsf
    \ifdim\@savsk>\z@
      \nobreak \hskip\z@skip  % <------
      \ignorespaces
    \fi
  \fi}
```

So as you can see clearly `\nobreak \hskip\z@skip` causes that extra vertical space. The `fixltx2e` package documentation states that this was suggested by Donald Arseneau to fix the bug "No hyphenation in first word after float environment" (page 18).

**Update:** The actual bug report can be found [here](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3498&category=LaTeX&responsible=anyone&state=anything&keyword=&).